# Checking whether file contains only whitespace C++

Tags: c++, file, input, whitespace

I am trying to read input from a file in C++, and I need to give an error message if there is no input.

This statement works if the file is completely empty:

```
if (f.peek() == std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()) return error("Empty file");
```

where error() is a simple function:

```
int error(string message){
   cerr << "ERROR: " << message << "\n";
   return -1;
}
```

How can I check for files that contain only whitespace so I can raise the same error? Such as 7 newlines?
My should continue executing normally if the file contains anything but only whitespace characters.

Comment: You have to read and inspect every character then. [`std::isspace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) may come in handy to do that.

Comment: What are the chances of a file containing only whitespace? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @Neil True that.

Comment: I only want to check for a file containing only whitespace. My program correctly parses a file with extra spaces but I want it to give an error if it is just a text file full of spaces or newlines.

Comment: Well, no, what you want is code that gives an error whenever it gets incorrect input, of whatever type.

Comment: @Neil It does, every time, except for the scenario which I posted. So I am asking specifically about this case.

Comment: Then you need some code to illustrate your problem. Reading the entire file, before doing any useful processing,  to check for whitespace is not sensible.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I was asking if there was a way to check in a similar fashion to checking for an empty file but the real solution was checking after parsing text. You are right about this being an XY problem, now that I am familiar with this term I will ask properly next time. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Scanning the file in advance if it only contains whitespaces would be ***very inefficient***.

I believe what you really need, is to keep track if some non-whitespace data could be read at all, and raise the error if not:

```
  std::string line;
  std::vector<std::string> lines_with_data;
  while(std::getline(f,line)) {
      // check if line is empty or contains only whitespace
      if(!(line.empty() ||
          (std::find_if_not(line.begin(),line.end(),std::isspace) != line.end())) {
           lines_with_data.push_back(line);
      }          
  }
  if(lines_with_data.empty()) { // No data could be found
      return error("Empty file");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach worked (checking after parsing) and I was mistaken trying to check in a similar manner to checking for an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) over the file input and check individual characters with `std:isspace()`, I suppose.

But I wonder if this is *really* what you want to do. Why not try to read whatever it is you want to read, and only worry about things when you fail your reading/parsing?

Answer (score 0):

reading characters and checking with `std::isspace` may help. something like this:

```
char c;
bool isEmpty = true;
while (f.get(c))
{
  if(!std::isspace(c))
  {
    isEmpty = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

this way, `isEmpty` will be what it says